# C# Core: Generic View in Razor pages for performing CRUD Operations for multiple tables using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ado.net, razor-pages

I'm beginning with a new project in **Razor pages** ( using .NET 6).

I have 150 plus lookup tables in the database that require CRUD operations. It will cost me 150+ pages and a significant amount of time.

To work on this, I need something that looks generic. Is it possible to write a Generic Razor page in C# that meets my needs?

Comment: We need a little more info to help you effectively. Can you provide a view example? Will all the models for the views have the same properties and will the views be laid out the same?

Comment: @clhereistian, Thank you for your response and support. Each model has its own set of attributes. This is our primary challenge.